# Choosing transformer for precision power supply design

Tags: power-supply, transformer, precision

I am trying to figure out what specification transformer I need to design a linear precision power supply which has 3 channels operation with certain requirements.

1. All the 3 channels have total power limit of 30 W each. Variable voltage and current. 0-12 V and 0-3 A.
2. A digital microcontroller for controlling and maintaining the precision output of both the voltage and current. This circuit might operate at around 5 V @ 1 A or 3.3 V @ 1 A. Just assuming this for now.
3. All the 3 channels should be able to hold a maximum power of 30 W continuously. So, total 90 W continuous across all the 3 channels.
4. Required precision is around 3 decimal places on both the voltage and current.

What specification transformer I should use in this type of use case? What secondary winding power requirements do I need? What voltages and amps rating on the secondary coils? And, how do I calculate these values?

Comment: You keep repeating the word "precision" but don't even mention what do you mean by precision and how much precision you require and for which parameters. For those specs you give, you could just buy three cheap lab power supplies.

Comment: @Justme I didn't ask for suggestions on what I could do rather than building the psu. Also, the question is updated with the amount of precision I was seeking for.

Comment: Fair enough. I just asked if that is an option, since you seem to be worried about the AC transformer, which in itself has very little to do with the precision as long as it can provide the volts/amps/power for your control electronics. It's the control electronics after it that makes the precision part, and you need to have a precision of about 1mV with 12V range - that's 83 parts per million of precision and requires at least a 14-bit DAC. Not to mention sense leads for voltage feedback, to provide the required precision at the load, to null out wire resistances, etc.

Comment: I did write a reply, but deleted it again.  The transformer and the precision are largely unrelated.  That's what the regulators are for.  But it's impossible to specify the transformer without having a design and/or general specification for what it will be powering.  If the outputs need to be isolated from each other, that makes a big difference.

Comment: +1 on what SimonB said, your transformer has practically nothing to do with precision. Just think about mains voltage fluctuations, how will you regulate them away? By the time you have done that, you will see that the "precision" of the transformer has become irrelevant.

Comment: @Justme I will discuss about the precision part on other questions later on. Just trying to figure out the transformer and mains part first. Just wanna find out a transformer which will be capable to meet the current and voltage requirements of each of those 3 channels and the control circuitry continuously. Simon All the 3 channels will be fully isolated.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer has to supply enough average current for your maximum current output, and enough minimum voltage for your maximum voltage output, at your maximum current. It's irrelevant to precision, except for the ripple caveat below.

Your max current output is 3 A. Assuming a rectifier/capacitor stage after the transformer, the transformer will need a higher RMS rating, as the current pulses taken have a higher RMS than average DC. You will do well to run these through a simulator, as they vary with reservoir capacitor size, but a factor of 1.2 is often quoted (if I get the time I'll try to find a reference for this), so allow at least 3.6 A per channel, more if your simulation says so.

Your max output is 12 V. You'll want some headroom for the regulators, perhaps 3 V, which makes the minimum reservoir capacitor voltage 15 V. You may want to exceed this if you have a tough output ripple specification to achieve and your regulator has limited PSRR at low headroom. Size your reservoir caps to allow a few volts ripple, so 18 V peak after the rectifier diodes, so 20 V peak before the diodes. That's about 14 Vrms, on load, minimum.

Is this a hobby project, so you'll want 14 V secondary voltage at your nominal mains voltage? Or is it a professional design, where you'll need to achieve that even at the lowest supply voltage permitted for your locale (for instance in the UK, 216.2 V to 253 V).

The logic supply is trivial compared to the outputs. You could linearly regulate down from 18 V, or better still use a DC-DC buck to get your 5 V. Or you could use a separate low voltage winding or even a separate transformer to supply it. Add the appropriate power depending on method to your transformer ratings.

Comment: It is a hobby project but I want to keep it as professional as possible because I am trying to learn power supply designs through designing one on my own with professional requirements and standards in mind. Your explanation is really good Neil. I will try to find a transformer with those ratings. BTW, can you please point me towards a good simulator? Haven't used any before.

Comment: LTSpice is free from analog.com. It's a bit clunky to drive, but it works well and is the de facto standard for hobbyists. It's available for win/mac, and runs under wine in linux.

Comment: With something of that output power, professionals would be reaching for a power factor corrected SMPS from mains, rather than a 'big iron' transformer.